# How to ensure that LAN connection is preferred over wireless on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance, ip

When I'm connected to both LAN and wireless, I prefer that LAN be used since it's much more faster.

However, from Task Manager, I'm seeing that wireless is being used all the time. I saw the other link : http://goo.gl/aLfWL where I need to change the metric.

I've changed both IPv4 and IPv6 metric numbers for both my LAN and wireless to the following values

`WIRELESS :20`

`LAN :10`

What am I doing wrong and how do I get to use the LAN?

P.S : BTW, sometime back using the LAN made my downloads way faster but something has happened in  the last few months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Change adapter settings`. Then in the menu (Hold ALT down if you don't see it), click `Advanced>Advanced settings` and move the wired connection to the top.